# Error: How do I get the daterangepicker js variable to echo in a php file PHP JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, html

My problem here is when I try to submit a date range from start to end, it can't seem to show the value or variable in my date2.php file and even in the console log(f12) The console log only reads the "apply event fired.. blabla". The other 4 console.log too are not being read. 
I don't know what happened..

My code in **date2.php**

```
<div class="x_content">
    <div class="well" style="overflow: auto">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="reportrange_right" class="pull-left" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>
                <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    echo "<script>document.writeln(startdate)</script>";
    echo "<script>document.writeln(enddate)</script>";
?>
```

**custom.js file code:**

```
$('#reportrange_right').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log("apply event fired, start/end dates are " + picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + picker.endDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    var startdate = picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY');
    var enddate = picker.endDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY');
    console.log(startdate);
    console.log(enddate);
    console.log(picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    $.post('date2.php', {
        _startdate: startdate,
        _enddate: enddate
    }).done(function() {});
    location.href = '../production/date2.php';
});
```

It would help me a lot. Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure what you're actually trying to do here. First you're making a post using Ajax, then you're redirecting the client on success? But it's not the same file you're redirecting to either (different URLS)? Then in your `date2.php`, you're trying to console log `startdate` and `enddate` in JS. Have you set those js variables on that page? Why even echo them using PHP? This code is very strange and its _very_ unclear what you're actually trying to do. It might be a misunderstanding about client side (js) vs sever side (php).

Comment: I haven't set them up on the php page, i'm new to js actually

Comment: Then you can't really console log them. `date2.php` is a new request/page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem. This should fix it. This should of course come with all the warnings about whether or not you're loading all your js files properly on date2.php. I can't account for all of that in my answer.

```
<?php

//date2.php
$startDate = ""; //declaring start and end in case they come up empty in the if statement
$endDate = "";
    if($_POST{'_startDate']){
//Strictly speaking you don't need to make these in to new variables
//It's just easier to use them later.
        $startDate = $_POST['_startDate'];
        $endDate = $_POST['_endDate'];
        //Now you can put the posted variables where you need them.
    }
?>
<!-- You can also just write in the variables anywhere you like -->
<p><?php echo $startDate;?></p> <!-- for example -->
<div class="x_content">
    <div class="well" style="overflow: auto">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="reportrange_right" class="pull-left" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>
          <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var startDate = '<?php echo $startDate; ?>';
    var endDate = '<?php echo $endDate; ?>';
    console.log(startDate + " : " + endDate);
    document.writeIn(startDate);
    document.writeIn(endDate);
    </script>
```

Comment: In PHP 7, you can simply do : `$startDate = $_POST['_startDate'] ?? '';`. It's the same as: `$startDate = isset($_POST['_startDate']) ? $_POST['_startDate'] : '';`

Comment: I know, but the way I did it is more readable as an example. In general, I'll write a bit more code if needed in order to make something more easily read as long as performance isn't impacted.

Comment: It's hard to say since I don't know what the rest of your code is doing and it's been a while since I used the jQuery date picker. But the code I provided will get your variables in to your date2.php file and you can use them wherever they're needed.

Comment: Much appreciated.